# Can't loop through sqlite statement using SQLITE_ROW Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I need to loop through a sqlite db but the function i'm using doesn't work at all, 
this is the code i'm using:

```
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"CarrelloMese.sqlite"]];
    NSUInteger helper;
    helper = 0;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &Carrello) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString *checkSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT FROM CarrelloMese"];

        const char *insert_stmt = [checkSQL UTF8String];

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(Carrello, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL)) {

            while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                [indexProdotti insertObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)] atIndex:helper];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(Carrello);
    }
```

When it reaches the `While` it doesn't enter, but I can't understand what's the problem.. The values are stored correctly on the DB (I checked with SqliteManager) and If I use a Count function within the app the count is correct, is there a problem with the code?

Comment: Why aren't you reporting error messages using `sqlite3_errmsg()`?

Comment: Further: there are so many nice wrappers for sqlite. Why don't you use them to get rid of all that low level stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be correct. You forgot to add  * in query.

Try this:

```
NSString *checkSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM CarrelloMese"];
```

Comment: Sure, the `*` is missing, but the statement itself is nonsense: use  `NSString *checkSQL = @"SELECT * FROM CarrelloMese";`

Comment: Better still `const char *insert_stmt = "SELECT * FROM CarrelloMese";`.